# Set x axis range in SAS using proc univariate?

Tags: sas, histogram, axis

Right now I am using proc univariate to make a histogram in SAS.

```
proc univariate data=myData;
var myVar;
histogram / endpoints = 0 to 75 by 5;
run;
```

However, the output is not taking into account the endpoints option. Does anyone know what the problem could be?

Comment: When you say it's not taking into account the endpoints option what do you mean?

Comment: I mean that the x axis of the output histogram extends from 0 to 500 instead of 0 to 75.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The documentation states:

> The procedure uses the same values for all variables.
>   The range of endpoints must cover the range of the data.

There's also a WARNING in my log when this occurs:

> WARNING: The ENDPOINTS= list was extended to accommodate the data.

https://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/procstat/63104/HTML/default/viewer.htm#procstat_univariate_sect013.htm

If you'd like to restrict the data to the values of 0 to 75 use a `WHERE`statement.

```
proc univariate data=myData;
WHERE myVar between 0 and 75;
var myVar;
histogram / endpoints = 0 to 75 by 5;
run;
```

Comment: Note that using a `where` statement will change the default histogram calculations (which are shown as a percentage of total).  I wonder if there is a simple way to 'zoom' the chart into just the buckets you want to look at and leave the calculations untouched... useful if say you have a skewed distribution with a long tail, but you don't care about the tail.

Comment: @RobertPenridge yes, today I would use SGPLOT for this and customize the values to the graph as desired.